# How to make visual studio run TestInitialize once when doing integration test?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, integration-testing

When I run all tests, the method decorated with `[TestInitialize]` attribute, gets executed for every test method I have.

The tests are of type integration test, to test database access logic. And in the method with `[TestInitialize]` attribute, I insert some test data into the database which causes the following exception when executed more than once:

> Result Message:    Initialization method
>   ......FilterRepositoryTests.Initialize
>   threw exception. System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException:
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while
>   updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: **Cannot insert duplicate key row in
>   object 'dbo.User' with unique index 'IX_Name'**. The duplicate key
>   value is (Person 1). The statement has been terminated..

Inserting the data takes some time, so I rather not delete and recreate the database for every test method I have.

So how can I execute an initialization/setup method only once for all test?

Comment: If you only want to setup the data once for the entire test class, have you looked into the `ClassInitialize` attribute?

Comment: No I didn't know of it's existence, but that worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [ClassInitialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classinitializeattribute.aspx) attribute which will be invoked once for all the test methods in that class.

Once done with the tests, you may need to cleanup with [ClassCleanup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classcleanupattribute.aspx) attribute.